# Kafka producer keeps disconnecting

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to run a standalone java program using Kafka producer but the producer keeps disconnecting.

Initially, I was receiving `Broker not available error` but was able to fix it by updating the connection address.

Beneath is the error log, I keep getting

```
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -1 disconnected.
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 0 due to node -1 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 17483ms, elapsed time since send: 17483ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected  
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -1 disconnected.
 to node -1 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 28755ms, elapsed time since send: 28755ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected  
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms.
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -1 disconnected.
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 2 due to node -1 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 21320ms, elapsed time since send: 21320ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected  
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Metrics scheduler closed
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Metrics reporters closed
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - App info kafka.producer for producer-1 unregistered
```

Comment: Seems like a network problem. Check the broker is actually running / healthy... What do you mean by "fix by updating network address"? What were you using before, if not `localhost:9092`?

Comment: Also, debug with `kafka-console-producer` before running your own java code